# How to adjust ColorFunction to scale the clipped areas in ListDensityPlot?

Tags: plotting, color

I have a data set I am trying to visualize, however some of the values seem to be extra large and it's just clipped and blanks are left. I want to rescale or whatever in such a way as this white areas would be colored too appropriately.

The first image is what I get in *Mathematica* and the second is what it is supposed to be scaling-wise (produced by some software written for matlab).[image]

[image]

Update on xzczd comment:

[image]

```
picdat2st={{1.78495, 2.03952, 1827.69}, {1.70419, 2.06639, 5134.99}, {1.62028, 
  2.09266, 8011.46}, {1.53321, 2.1182, 1632.02}, {1.44301, 2.14288, 
  537.237}, {1.34972, 2.16656, 415.189}, {1.25341, 2.1891, 
  392.146}, {1.15418, 2.21038, 382.}, {1.05216, 2.23024, 
  388.875}, {0.947498, 2.24854, 321.228}, {0.840383, 2.26517, 
  375.435}, {0.731027, 2.27998, 396.758}, {0.619669, 2.29287, 
  445.896}, {0.506576, 2.30373, 471.853}, {0.392039, 2.31246, 
  437.823}, {0.276366, 2.31901, 434.35}, {0.159884, 2.3233, 
  444.573}, {0.0429301, 2.32529, 454.344}, {-0.0741507, 2.32499, 
  450.767}, {-0.168854, 2.32311, 440.324}, {1.81201, 1.9663, 
  2023.2}, {1.73072, 1.99302, 10549.6}, {1.64616, 2.01917, 
  7248.22}, {1.55831, 2.04463, 1258.35}, {1.4672, 2.06925, 
  584.484}, {1.37286, 2.09291, 465.738}, {1.27536, 2.11546, 
  441.121}, {1.17479, 2.13676, 478.56}, {1.0713, 2.15666, 
  565.977}, {0.965022, 2.17503, 422.213}, {0.856162, 2.19172, 
  475.28}, {0.744936, 2.2066, 532.408}, {0.631596, 2.21956, 
  662.432}, {0.516421, 2.23049, 598.028}, {0.399717, 2.23928, 
  502.683}, {0.28181, 2.24587, 478.437}, {0.163045, 2.25019, 
  472.427}, {0.0437805, 2.2522, 472.823}, {-0.0756191, 2.25189, 
  470.561}, {-0.172193, 2.25, 471.281}, {1.83885, 1.88973, 
  1185.28}, {1.75707, 1.9162, 2442.77}, {1.6719, 1.94214, 
  1540.14}, {1.5833, 1.96742, 714.008}, {1.49131, 1.9919, 
  535.022}, {1.39594, 2.01545, 503.667}, {1.29728, 2.03792, 
  576.124}, {1.1954, 2.05916, 1836.53}, {1.09045, 2.07904, 
  2462.35}, {0.982577, 2.09739, 717.044}, {0.871982, 2.11409, 
  687.435}, {0.758893, 2.12899, 1232.7}, {0.643572, 2.14197, 
  2156.07}, {0.526312, 2.15293, 1290.09}, {0.407434, 2.16175, 
  845.909}, {0.287284, 2.16836, 783.081}, {0.166225, 2.17269, 
  756.737}, {0.0446357, 2.17471, 747.591}, {-0.077096, 2.1744, 
  744.444}, {-0.17555, 2.1725, 745.24}, {1.86537, 1.80976, 
  539.165}, {1.78314, 1.83587, 720.351}, {1.69738, 1.86149, 
  675.632}, {1.60808, 1.88648, 510.616}, {1.51524, 1.91072, 
  453.79}, {1.41889, 1.93406, 470.088}, {1.31909, 1.95635, 
  697.79}, {1.21593, 1.97746, 2205.63}, {1.10955, 1.99722, 
  1595.64}, {1.0001, 2.01548, 800.204}, {0.887782, 2.03212, 
  2247.21}, {0.772842, 2.04697, 19653.7}, {0.655549, 2.05993, 
  18990.3}, {0.53621, 2.07086, 3034.16}, {0.415161, 2.07967, 
  1222.24}, {0.292766, 2.08628, 977.361}, {0.16941, 2.09061, 
  909.967}, {0.0454926, 2.09263, 895.116}, {-0.0785756, 2.09232, 
  892.999}, {-0.178914, 2.09042, 898.454}, {1.89145, 1.72633, 
  378.813}, {1.8088, 1.75196, 464.135}, {1.72251, 1.77714, 
  484.287}, {1.63254, 1.80174, 438.434}, {1.5389, 1.82562, 
  430.837}, {1.44159, 1.84864, 459.534}, {1.34069, 1.87066, 
  505.533}, {1.23629, 1.89152, 616.045}, {1.1285, 1.91107, 
  670.658}, {1.0175, 1.92917, 822.236}, {0.903492, 1.94566, 
  2673.34}, {0.786723, 1.9604, 8689.56}, {0.667476, 1.97327, 
  3612.11}, {0.546071, 1.98413, 1212.63}, {0.422863, 1.99289, 
  1082.8}, {0.298232, 1.99946, 1187.66}, {0.172586, 2.00377, 
  1353.77}, {0.0463473, 2.00578, 1512.1}, {-0.0800514, 2.00547, 
  1473.99}, {-0.182268, 2.00358, 1348.91}, {1.91697, 1.63942, 
  319.431}, {1.83395, 1.66445, 368.978}, {1.74716, 1.68906, 
  394.271}, {1.65656, 1.71313, 390.086}, {1.56215, 1.73653, 
  421.089}, {1.46394, 1.75912, 431.808}, {1.36198, 1.78074, 
  479.505}, {1.25636, 1.80126, 616.576}, {1.14721, 1.82051, 
  699.549}, {1.0347, 1.83834, 626.134}, {0.919034, 1.8546, 
  877.202}, {0.800466, 1.86915, 1310.38}, {0.679292, 1.88185, 
  949.271}, {0.555847, 1.89259, 923.8}, {0.430501, 1.90125, 
  1069.26}, {0.303656, 1.90775, 1205.47}, {0.175739, 1.91202, 
  1170.12}, {0.0471957, 1.91401, 1184.29}, {-0.0815162, 1.9137, 
  1169.5}, {-0.185597, 1.91183, 1139.08}, {1.94179, 1.54901, 
  304.686}, {1.85844, 1.5733, 345.25}, {1.7712, 1.59721, 
  384.68}, {1.68002, 1.62063, 404.122}, {1.58489, 1.64343, 
  423.399}, {1.48581, 1.66545, 497.917}, {1.38284, 1.68656, 
  764.068}, {1.27606, 1.7066, 755.03}, {1.16559, 1.72543, 
  570.134}, {1.05161, 1.74289, 494.911}, {0.934321, 1.75883, 
  725.884}, {0.813995, 1.77311, 915.266}, {0.690933, 1.78558, 
  756.958}, {0.565483, 1.79612, 688.804}, {0.438034, 1.80464, 
  692.212}, {0.309006, 1.81103, 718.634}, {0.178849, 1.81522, 
  764.402}, {0.0480328, 1.81718, 803.705}, {-0.0829616, 1.81688, 
  801.345}, {-0.188882, 1.81504, 767.184}, {1.9658, 1.45512, 
  293.24}, {1.88215, 1.47853, 339.236}, {1.79449, 1.50161, 
  402.035}, {1.70277, 1.52424, 412.258}, {1.60697, 1.54628, 
  487.202}, {1.50708, 1.56761, 918.372}, {1.40315, 1.58807, 
  1517.19}, {1.29525, 1.60752, 684.167}, {1.18352, 1.62581, 
  608.111}, {1.06811, 1.64279, 630.17}, {0.94926, 1.6583, 
  708.136}, {0.827225, 1.67221, 715.809}, {0.702324, 1.68436, 
  663.49}, {0.574919, 1.69465, 757.553}, {0.445414, 1.70296, 
  807.137}, {0.31425, 1.70919, 902.67}, {0.181898, 1.71329, 
  1006.44}, {0.0488535, 1.71521, 959.113}, {-0.0843786, 1.71491, 
  955.014}, {-0.192102, 1.71311, 993.821}, {1.98883, 1.3578, 
  306.065}, {1.90492, 1.38019, 358.183}, {1.81689, 1.40228, 
  409.085}, {1.72468, 1.42397, 470.317}, {1.62825, 1.44512, 
  716.558}, {1.5276, 1.4656, 1114.57}, {1.42276, 1.48528, 
  1322.91}, {1.31381, 1.50401, 819.898}, {1.20087, 1.52163, 
  787.657}, {1.08411, 1.53801, 638.447}, {0.963748, 1.55298, 
  783.794}, {0.840066, 1.56642, 814.958}, {0.713388, 1.57817, 
  1161.81}, {0.584088, 1.58812, 3194.75}, {0.452588, 1.59616, 
  1583.08}, {0.31935, 1.6022, 1160.82}, {0.184865, 1.60617, 
  898.361}, {0.049652, 1.60803, 781.263}, {-0.0857573, 1.60774, 
  783.835}, {-0.195235, 1.606, 869.17}, {2.01075, 1.25713, 
  339.998}, {1.92661, 1.27834, 371.841}, {1.83826, 1.2993, 
  445.627}, {1.7456, 1.31989, 614.221}, {1.6486, 1.34, 
  698.537}, {1.54724, 1.3595, 628.375}, {1.44155, 1.37825, 
  1082.16}, {1.33161, 1.39611, 1107.25}, {1.21752, 1.41293, 
  587.829}, {1.09947, 1.42858, 485.277}, {0.977677, 1.4429, 
  632.263}, {0.852421, 1.45576, 705.947}, {0.72404, 1.46701, 
  1263.06}, {0.592922, 1.47655, 3098.5}, {0.459504, 1.48426, 
  1179.85}, {0.324266, 1.49006, 797.397}, {0.187725, 1.49387, 
  558.64}, {0.0504221, 1.49565, 495.202}, {-0.0870869, 1.49537, 
  497.449}, {-0.198256, 1.4937, 544.34}, {2.0314, 1.1532, 
  798.915}, {1.94708, 1.17309, 468.361}, {1.85843, 1.19276, 
  877.965}, {1.76538, 1.21211, 725.098}, {1.66785, 1.23103, 
  543.75}, {1.56584, 1.24938, 595.564}, {1.45937, 1.26705, 
  997.745}, {1.3485, 1.2839, 752.533}, {1.23334, 1.29979, 
  546.546}, {1.11408, 1.31458, 486.437}, {0.990933, 1.32812, 
  571.462}, {0.864188, 1.34029, 516.255}, {0.734192, 1.35096, 
  500.645}, {0.601345, 1.36, 550.113}, {0.4661, 1.36731, 
  555.508}, {0.328959, 1.37281, 521.624}, {0.190456, 1.37642, 
  441.374}, {0.0511573, 1.37811, 421.078}, {-0.0883562, 1.37785, 
  422.512}, {-0.201139, 1.37626, 438.548}, {2.05063, 1.04617, 
  2138.86}, {1.96616, 1.06458, 1156.23}, {1.87726, 1.08282, 
  7750.11}, {1.78385, 1.10077, 1022.95}, {1.68586, 1.11833, 
  556.374}, {1.58326, 1.1354, 643.547}, {1.47607, 1.15184, 
  635.241}, {1.36434, 1.16753, 924.871}, {1.2482, 1.18234, 
  720.683}, {1.12781, 1.19614, 512.825}, {1.0034, 1.20879, 
  523.138}, {0.875262, 1.22016, 438.654}, {0.743751, 1.23013, 
  412.371}, {0.60928, 1.23859, 393.874}, {0.472319, 1.24543, 
  367.831}, {0.333383, 1.25058, 367.595}, {0.193031, 1.25397, 
  383.344}, {0.0518507, 1.25555, 436.024}, {-0.0895534, 1.2553, 
  429.837}, {-0.203858, 1.25382, 384.754}, {2.06831, 0.936199, 
  843.882}, {1.98371, 0.952998, 1917.76}, {1.8946, 0.969644, 
  7003.12}, {1.80088, 0.986048, 932.8}, {1.70247, 1.00211, 
  713.738}, {1.59934, 1.01773, 697.005}, {1.4915, 1.0328, 
  892.06}, {1.379, 1.04719, 7683.77}, {1.26195, 1.06078, 
  1443.77}, {1.14053, 1.07346, 511.445}, {1.01496, 1.08508, 
  1925.16}, {0.885535, 1.09554, 1528.57}, {0.752625, 1.10472, 
  433.507}, {0.616651, 1.11251, 357.109}, {0.478096, 1.11882, 
  351.759}, {0.337495, 1.12356, 403.744}, {0.195425, 1.12668, 
  617.661}, {0.0524954, 1.12814, 1287.39}, {-0.0906664, 1.12791, 
  1183.39}, {-0.206386, 1.12654, 620.65}, {2.08429, 0.823513, 
  416.356}, {1.99959, 0.838554, 735.876}, {1.9103, 0.85347, 
  983.25}, {1.8163, 0.868181, 575.844}, {1.71753, 0.8826, 
  649.379}, {1.61394, 0.896633, 564.542}, {1.50552, 0.910177, 
  717.074}, {1.39232, 0.923125, 2427.33}, {1.27447, 0.935366, 
  595.147}, {1.15211, 0.946785, 394.995}, {1.02549, 0.95727, 
  2653.32}, {0.894902, 0.966709, 1319.08}, {0.760721, 0.974994, 
  447.996}, {0.623378, 0.98203, 376.956}, {0.483371, 0.987727, 
  448.057}, {0.34125, 0.992016, 1053.14}, {0.197612, 0.994838, 
  3063.02}, {0.0530843, 0.996156, 13305.3}, {-0.0916832, 0.995953, 
  11467.8}, {-0.208696, 0.994713, 3106.66}, {2.09843, 0.708358, 
  424.431}, {2.01365, 0.721509, 637.066}, {1.92421, 0.734561, 
  635.707}, {1.82999, 0.747444, 718.714}, {1.73091, 0.76008, 
  642.244}, {1.62691, 0.772387, 562.723}, {1.51798, 0.784274, 
  657.608}, {1.40418, 0.795646, 592.402}, {1.28561, 0.806404, 
  393.274}, {1.16243, 0.816447, 316.573}, {1.03488, 0.825674, 
  452.827}, {0.90326, 0.833985, 380.875}, {0.767948, 0.841284, 
  321.274}, {0.629386, 0.847484, 452.992}, {0.488084, 0.852508, 
  519.509}, {0.344607, 0.85629, 503.274}, {0.199566, 0.858779, 
  1066.2}, {0.0536108, 0.859942, 2717.47}, {-0.0925921, 0.859763, 
  2456.02}, {-0.21076, 0.858669, 1087.86}, {2.11061, 0.591013, 
  526.767}, {2.02577, 0.602157, 845.757}, {1.93621, 0.613223, 
  671.752}, {1.84181, 0.624154, 818.003}, {1.74246, 0.634882, 
  629.263}, {1.63812, 0.645337, 688.464}, {1.52877, 0.655442, 
  925.687}, {1.41445, 0.665115, 538.77}, {1.29526, 0.674272, 
  373.721}, {1.17138, 0.682825, 275.867}, {1.04302, 0.690687, 
  341.5}, {0.910511, 0.697772, 325.22}, {0.774221, 0.703997, 
  1082.54}, {0.634603, 0.709287, 615.925}, {0.492178, 0.713575, 
  362.696}, {0.347523, 0.716803, 481.387}, {0.201265, 0.718929, 
  633.326}, {0.0540683, 0.719922, 1819.85}, {-0.0933819, 0.719769, 
  1470.48}, {-0.212553, 0.718835, 625.534}, {2.12072, 0.471793, 
  610.152}, {2.03584, 0.480825, 979.505}, {1.94619, 0.4898, 
  760.081}, {1.85164, 0.498669, 792.42}, {1.75208, 0.507379, 
  723.633}, {1.64745, 0.515872, 1067.03}, {1.53775, 0.524084, 
  2803.8}, {1.423, 0.53195, 662.312}, {1.30331, 0.5394, 
  387.344}, {1.17884, 0.546362, 271.95}, {1.04982, 0.552764, 
  340.563}, {0.916569, 0.558536, 441.55}, {0.779463, 0.563609, 
  694.594}, {0.638964, 0.567922, 458.47}, {0.495601, 0.571419, 
  439.463}, {0.349961, 0.574052, 494.472}, {0.202686, 0.575786, 
  806.385}, {0.054451, 0.576596, 3416.79}, {-0.0940426, 0.576471, 
  2450.05}, {-0.214053, 0.575709, 775.546}, {2.12867, 0.351038, 
  615.69}, {2.04377, 0.357873, 588.443}, {1.95405, 0.364667, 
  838.416}, {1.85938, 0.371384, 732.598}, {1.75965, 0.377984, 
  600.873}, {1.65481, 0.384421, 819.991}, {1.54484, 0.390649, 
  954.845}, {1.42976, 0.396617, 500.367}, {1.30967, 0.402271, 
  372.023}, {1.18474, 0.407557, 260.757}, {1.05519, 0.412419, 
  369.087}, {0.921355, 0.416804, 746.952}, {0.783607, 0.42066, 
  427.876}, {0.642412, 0.423939, 450.042}, {0.498308, 0.426597, 
  473.059}, {0.35189, 0.4286, 594.208}, {0.203809, 0.429919, 
  747.748}, {0.0547537, 0.430535, 6111.43}, {-0.0945652, 0.43044, 
  3108.83}, {-0.21524, 0.42986, 716.83}, {2.13439, 0.229114, 
  997.13}, {2.04946, 0.233685, 712.211}, {1.95969, 0.23823, 
  1480.22}, {1.86494, 0.242725, 904.181}, {1.76511, 0.247142, 
  596.304}, {1.66011, 0.251453, 599.706}, {1.54994, 0.255624, 
  525.697}, {1.43462, 0.259622, 434.205}, {1.31425, 0.263412, 
  359.371}, {1.18899, 0.266955, 271.298}, {1.05907, 0.270216, 
  584.404}, {0.924808, 0.273157, 908.817}, {0.786597, 0.275744, 
  506.199}, {0.644901, 0.277943, 455.928}, {0.500262, 0.279727, 
  578.227}, {0.353283, 0.281072, 596.414}, {0.204621, 0.281957, 
  771.863}, {0.0549723, 0.28237, 16003.2}, {-0.0949426, 0.282307, 
  3865.21}, {-0.216097, 0.281917, 711.665}, {2.13781, 0.106403, 
  6973.77}, {2.05287, 0.108665, 1616.58}, {1.96308, 0.110914, 
  14076.}, {1.86828, 0.113139, 2715.93}, {1.76838, 0.115326, 
  637.166}, {1.66329, 0.117461, 558.886}, {1.553, 0.119527, 
  509.304}, {1.43754, 0.121507, 861.807}, {1.317, 0.123385, 
  487.462}, {1.19154, 0.12514, 374.141}, {1.06139, 0.126756, 
  4292.47}, {0.926882, 0.128214, 2429.74}, {0.788392, 0.129497, 
  554.28}, {0.646396, 0.130587, 551.724}, {0.501436, 0.131472, 
  717.561}, {0.354119, 0.132138, 792.467}, {0.205108, 0.132577, 
  1605.26}, {0.0551037, 0.132782, 8139.69}, {-0.0951694, 0.132751, 
  10556.5}, {-0.216612, 0.132558, 1377.68}, {2.13893, -0.00807573, 
  4350.23}, {2.05399, -0.0079823, 688.677}, {1.96419, -0.00788938, 
  12472.2}, {1.86938, -0.00779747, 1577.91}, {1.76945, -0.00770711, 
  227.68}, {1.66433, -0.00761893, 207.15}, {1.55401, -0.00753356, 
  203.058}, {1.4385, -0.00745172, 1197.88}, {1.3179, -0.00737414, 
  395.971}, {1.19238, -0.00730158, 280.762}, {1.06216, -0.00723479, 
  15818.8}, {0.927563, -0.00717454, 4398.24}, {0.788982, -0.00712154, 
  436.895}, {0.646887, -0.00707646, 543.133}, {0.501821, -0.00703989, 
  762.149}, {0.354394, -0.00701234, 1064.17}, {0.205268, -0.00699419, 
  2536.61}, {0.0551468, -0.00698571, 
  10782.7}, {-0.0952438, -0.00698702, 15840.2}, {-0.216781, -0.006995,
   2311.23}}
```

Comment: What will happen if you add `PlotRange->All`?

Comment: Great! I forgot about it! Just updated the question with your suggestion.

Comment: So, your problem is solved? Or you actually want to obtain the same graph as the second one?

Comment: Solved pretty much.